# How do I get a &str or String from std::borrow::Cow<str>?

Tags: string, rust, concatenation

I have a [`Cow`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/borrow/enum.Cow.html):

```
use std::borrow::Cow;  // Cow = clone on write
let example = Cow::from("def")
```

I would like to get the `def` back out of it, in order to append it to another `String`:

```
let mut alphabet: String = "ab".to_string();
alphabet.push_str("c");
// here I would like to do:
alphabet.push_str(example);
```

This does not work and I don't see the appropriate method in `Cow` to get the `&str` or `String` back out.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Pass a reference to `example` (i.e. `&example`) to `push_str`.

```
let mut alphabet: String = "ab".to_string();
alphabet.push_str("c");  
alphabet.push_str(&example);
```

This works because `Cow` implements [`Deref`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ops/trait.Deref.html).

Comment: Ah that's how it works! I need to remember this for any future string like things which implement `Deref`.

Answer (score 92):

> How do I get a `&str`

1. Use `Borrow`:

   ```
   use std::borrow::Borrow;
   alphabet.push_str(example.borrow());
   ```
2. Use `AsRef`:

   ```
   alphabet.push_str(example.as_ref());
   ```
3. Use `Deref` explicitly:

   ```
   use std::ops::Deref;
   alphabet.push_str(example.deref());
   ```
4. Use `Deref` implicitly through a coercion:

   ```
   alphabet.push_str(&example);
   ```

> How do I get a `String`

1. Use `ToString`:

   ```
   example.to_string();
   ```
2. Use `Cow::into_owned`:

   ```
   example.into_owned();
   ```
3. Use any method to get a reference and then call `to_owned`:

   ```
   example.as_ref().to_owned();
   ```

Comment: Very helpful as well. If I could accept 2 answers, I would : )

Comment: Note for future readers: in "How do I get a `String`", `into_owned` consumes the `Cow` and allocates only in case of `Cow::Borrowed`, whereas `to_string` and `as_ref + to_owned` leave the `Cow` intact and unconditionally allocates.  They are equivalent for `Cow::Borrowed`, but analogous to a move vs. a clone for `Cow::Owned`.