# Rust: How to expand path, join path, and glob files?

Tags: ruby, rust, glob

I'm learning Rust and I'm trying to convert a simple Ruby example which does:

1. [File expand path](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/File.html#method-c-expand_path)
2. [File join paths](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/File.html#method-c-join)
3. [Dir glob](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Dir.html#method-c-glob)
4. Prints files found in Dir glob

Here's the Ruby example:

```rb
output_path = '~/Documents'
pattern = File.expand_path(File.join(output_path, '*', '**', '*.txt'))

Dir.glob(pattern) do |path|
  puts path
end
```

Bonus Nim example:

```
import os
import strformat
import glob

var outputPath = expandTilde("~/Documents")
var pattern = joinPath(outputPath, "*", "**", "*.txt")

for path in walkGlob(pattern):
  echo path
```

Here's what I have so far for Rust, however, it doesn't build:

```rust
use std::io;
use std::fs;
use std::path::PathBuf;
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    let output_path: io::Result<PathBuf> = fs::canonicalize("~/Documents");
    let pattern: PathBuf = [output_path, "*", "**", "*.txt"].iter().collect();
    for entry in glob(pattern).expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
        match entry {
            Ok(path) => println!("{:?}", path.display()),
            Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried different variations with no success.

I'm not sure [fs::canonicalize](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.canonicalize.html) actually expands tilde paths. I found an older crate which does: [shellexpand::tilde](https://docs.rs/shellexpand/2.1.0/shellexpand/fn.tilde.html).  However, I don't know how to deal with the output it gives.  It's not a `str` or `String`.

I'm also not sure if I need multiple levels of `match` on the `Result` and `Option` return values from some of those.  Ultimately `glob` wants a `str` and in all my variations, the first `output_path` value messes that up, or I don't know how to convert that to a `str`.

What am I missing? What is the idiomatic way to do this? So far the approaches I've tried seem too verbose. Is there a simple way to do this?

**UPDATE**

I eventually got it to work if I hard-coded the expanded path:

```rust
use std::path::PathBuf;
use glob::glob;

fn main() {
    let pattern_path_buf: PathBuf = ["", "/Users", "ejstembler", "Documents", "*", "**", "*.txt"].iter().collect();
    match pattern_path_buf.to_str() {
        Some(pattern) => {
            println!("{:?}", pattern);
            for entry in glob(pattern).expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
                match entry {
                    Ok(path) => println!("{:?}", path.display()),
                    Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
                }
            }
        },
        None => println!("no pattern_path_buf")
    }
}
```

One weird nuance, is that I had to add a blank string in the beginning of the PathBuf "" to get it to include a leading forward slash, otherwise it would be missing. I found that there's `std::path::MAIN_SEPARATOR`, however, I have no idea how to convert a `char` to a `&str`.

In any case, [@Joe_Jingyu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2567797/joe-jingyu) provided the accepted [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69242778/691816) with `shellexpand::tilde` working.  Thanks Joe!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my code of using [shellexpand::tilde](https://docs.rs/shellexpand/2.1.0/shellexpand/fn.tilde.html) to expand tilde.

```
use std::path::PathBuf;
use glob::glob;
use shellexpand;

fn main() {
    let expanded_path = shellexpand::tilde("~/Documents/");
    let pattern : PathBuf = [&expanded_path, "*", "**", "*.txt"].iter().collect();

    for entry in glob(pattern.to_str().unwrap()).expect("Failed to read glob pattern") {
        match entry {
            Ok(path) => println!("{:?}", path.display()),
            Err(e) => println!("{:?}", e),
        }
    }
}
```

Here is a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47147844/how-do-i-get-a-str-or-string-from-stdborrowcowstr) on how to get &str from a Cow returned from [shellexpand::tilde](https://docs.rs/shellexpand/2.1.0/shellexpand/fn.tilde.html).

Comment: Thanks! I eventually got it to work by hard-coding the path since I didn't know what to do with that `Cow<str>`. But I like your version much better!